# handling joins on multiple tables in hive

Tags: sql, join, hive

Below is the table structure of tables a,b,c,d and x

write a query to find id, i am expecting this can be done using case statement but not sure how to put it in query.

```
table a
id name address

table b
id name dept

table c
id name dept sal

table d
id name dept address

table x
id name dept address ......

a join x (on id)

if id is null then
a join b (on name and get id) then join x(on id)

if name is null then
a join c (on dept and get name) then join b (on name and get id) then join x(on id)

if dept is null then
a join d(on address get id) then join x on id
```

Comment: `a join c on dept` is not possible, since `a` has no `dept` column. Sample data and desired results are worth many pseudo code blocks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.